# Install 4.5 .Net Framework When Execting A Program (if not already installed)

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.5, prerequisites

Let's get right to it, is there a way to deploy 4.5 .Net Framework when running a program?

A little background info should be added...I need to a way to zip a bunch of PDFs. Right now, I'm creating a process that calls 7zip but realized that this program would need to be installed on every machine this program will be executed from, which not an ideal solution. So from a previous question I posted [ZipFuntion_Within_Visual_Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12629544/zip-function-within-visual-studio), I asked how this could be done and the ideal solution was to use the [ZipClass](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.zipfile.aspx), which is only available on the 4.5 .Net Framework.

Is there a way to check to see if this is installed and if not, install on the machines that need it, upon running the program? Could I also be referring to a Prerequisites?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does my .NET 4 application know .NET 4 is not installed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10032233/why-does-my-net-4-application-know-net-4-is-not-installed)

Comment: could be done via an installer prerequisite.